# Getting detailed logs for Amazon Cognito following a failed authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudtrail

*Please not that for the purposes of this question, I am not interested in the specifics of what I have misconfigure or the root cause of my issue, but the steps I should take to trouble shoot it.*

I have set up an Amazon Cognito user pool and client appliication in order to evaluate the product's oauth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow capabilities.

I am currently running my tests using Postman's Authorization management interface.

When I attempt to authenticate using the authorization code flow, I am currently getting a `500` responce from the `POST oauth2/token` endpoint with the message `{"error":"Internal Error"}`.

I would assume that at this point my next step should be to go and check the relevant logs in order to get to the bottom of this.

A quick Google or search of StackOverflow as well as the AWS documentation would suggest checking CloudTrail's Event history.

However when I check ColoudTrail, I find the logging information very limeted.

I do find 4 events under the `cognito-idp.amazonaws.com` event source, but these entries limit themselves to listing the user calls as well as the response calls Cognito sent back to the user:

```
OAuth2_Authorize_GET (302)
Login_GET (200)
CognitoAuthentication (200)
Token_POST (500)
```

At no point do I find any details that could provide me with more information as to the nature of "Internal Error" that has occured during the `Token_POST` call.

Is there any way to enable more detailed logging, or a different log or event source I can check that would provide me with more specific information?

To be clear, when I check the event record for any of the above listed log entries, I do get a JSON report, but this limites itself to describing what was sent by the client and responded by Cognito, not the nature of the server failure.

Thank you in advance.